# Sending Content (Message Body) along with 304 Not Modified header

Tags: http-headers

For static html pages, when the response header from the server is **304 Not Modified**, isn't it the server's responsibility to send back only the headers and not the message-body (html content) along with it ?

Whats the point in sending **304 Not Modified** if it comes along with the html content too ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no point to sending a message body with a 304 response.  In fact, the [**HTTP specification**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) says that the server must not do so.  If you have one that is, it's misbehaving according to the spec.

From the HTTP Specification:

> The 304 response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

Comment: My HTML file resides on a nginx server and on hitting F5, monitoring net activity using FireBug, the bytes returned is the same with response containing message body as well.

Comment: What's probably happening in your situation is your browser is getting the correctly formed 304 response from nginx and then pulling the page from its cache and passing it on to FireBug.  Do you have a tool that will show you the entire conversation?  Fiddler or WebScarab would show you the conversation.

Comment: Thanks. I just verified this using curl.
    curl --dump-header header.txt --header "If-Modified-Since: Sun, 08 Aug 2010 17:43:07 GMT" http://myurl.com/page.html

    cat header.txt

    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

    Server: nginx

    Date: Mon, 09 Aug 2010 23:14:26 GMT

    Connection: keep-alive

    ETag: "16f8016-43c-48d536ec440c0"


No message body !